# Regex that only works on browser tester

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tested my regex on [Regex testers](http://www.dailycoding.com/Utils/javascript/regexp_tester_javascript.html) and it worked, but I didn't get it to work on my code.

```
var mail = "chdelfosse@gmail.com";
var regExp = new RegExp("@(.*?)\.");
document.write(regExp.exec(mail)) ;
```

I get this result :

> @g,

I tried to add a backslash before the dot, and I got this :

> @gmail.,gmail

I also wanted to remove the "@" and the "." from the email, so I tried to use " (?:@) ", but I didn't get it to work (on Regex testers).

It's my first time trying to use Regex, and I don't get it. 
Why is there a comma ?

Comment: `@g,` because your regex matched literal `@`, then lazily matched any character , in your case `g`, and returned array had two elements, which were `toString()`'d, which uses `join()` which has a default separator of `,`.

Comment: @gdoron I wanted to take the domain name of the address mail, so everything between "@" and "."

Comment: @alex What if I don't want the comma ?

Comment: @Pointy doesn't `.*?` mean *make the `*` quantifier be lazy*?

Comment: @alex oh yes right; sorry about that. I've had a weird day :-)

Comment: @Pointy No worries, I forget things all the time too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to get the domain name:

```
/@(.+)\./
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QFzS7/)

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't return anything. Also doesn't work in Regex testers.

Comment: @user1828310. You need to use it correctly... Check the demo.

Comment: @user1828310. It gives you the first matched group- the chars matched according to the braces, in this case the domain name without the .suffix.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to do differently:

1. You need to double escape your backslash in the string so that one backslash still remains for the RegExp constructor or switch to the `/regex here/` syntax.
2. If you want just the subgroup in the parens, you need to refer to that specific subgroup.

Here's the code:

```
var mail = "chdelfosse@gmail.com";
console.log(mail.match(/@(.*?)\./)[1]);
```

Comment: I tried it, and it kind of works, but I get "@gmail.,gmail". I would only like it once, without the comma.

Comment: @user1828310 - I've modified the answer to get just the subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Faster than regex:

```
var emailAddress = "my.email@gmail.com";
var array_email = emailAddress.split("@");​​
alert('Account: ' + array_email[0] +'; Domain: ' + array_email[1]);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: **Maybe** faster, but doesn't do what he requested... :)

Comment: Oh I see ... he edited it and commented.... :O I will give a vup for better solution ;-)

Comment: @salih0vicX I tested it, but it doesn't display anything .. ?

Comment: @salih0vicX Oh, also, I didn't want the ".com" part